# How to set text to right of image on a togglebutton

Tags: android, image, togglebutton

I have a togglebutton with an image, but when I change the text of the button, the text is behind the image. I added extra spaces in the `setText()` function, but this doesn't scale well on different screen sizes.
So what can I do?

the xml for the toggle button auton_select.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

 <item android:state_checked="true" 
       android:drawable="@drawable/auto_select" /> <!-- pressed -->

 <item android:state_checked="false"
       android:drawable="@drawable/auto_unselect" /> <!-- unchecked -->

 <item android:drawable="@drawable/auto_unselect" /> <!-- default -->

</selector>
```

using the togglebutton xml in the layout

```
<ToggleButton
        android:id="@+id/auto_ring_button" 
        android:textOn="               test"
        android:textOff=" "
        android:disabledAlpha=".9"
        android:button="@drawable/auton_select"

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:onClick="showPopupR"
        />
```

Comment: Did you have the different background image?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to set image as compound drawable instead of background.

```
toggleButton.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.image, 0, 0, 0);
```

or in XML

```
android:drawableLeft="@drawable/image"
```

References:
[`setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29)
[`android:drawableLeft`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3adrawableLeft)

Comment: In the xml for the button, there is no `android:drawableLeft` attribute, so I can't use that

Comment: @rasen58 ToggleButton has `android:drawableLeft` attribute.

Comment: It does in the normal <ToggleButton/> tags but I have it in item tags, but the java code worked.

Comment: @Glotov do you know how to remove the drawable using java?

Comment: @rasen58 You can use selector in the layout XML: `android:drawableLeft="@drawable/selector"`

Comment: @rasen58 To remove drawable set with `setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds()` you can use `setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0,0,0,0)`